# Excel VBA: How to multiply last column containing data with the column before?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am still very new to VBA and am trying to multiply my last column (which changes monthly) by the values in the column before that one. What makes this difficult (for me) is that once this is executed, I need to add another column and multiply by the same column that the previous one was multiplied by. For example: My code performs a vlookup in the next available column, lets say that is column R. I then need to multiply the values in column R by the values in column Q (until the last row in column R). I then need to perform a new vlookup in column S, but still multiply it by the values in Q. Again, the columns change monthly. Here is my code so far, I have managed to figure out all the vlookups and everything, just having trouble multiplying my columns with previous column:

```
Sub vlookup5()
    Dim SourceLastRow As Long
    Dim OutputLastRow As Long
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

    Dim NextColumn As Long

    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Data1")
    Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
    With sourceSheet
         SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With outputSheet
        NextColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        .Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
             "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",6,0)*LastColumn"
        .Cells(OutputLastRow + 1, NextColumn).Formula = "=SUM(" & Chr(64 + NextColumn) & "4:" & Chr(64 + NextColumn) & OutputLastRow & ")*1000"
    End With
    End Sub

 Sub vlookup6()
        Dim SourceLastRow As Long
        Dim OutputLastRow As Long
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

        Dim NextColumn As Long

    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Data1")
    Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
    With sourceSheet
         SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With outputSheet
        NextColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        .Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
             "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",7,0)"
        .Cells(OutputLastRow + 1, NextColumn).Formula = "=SUM(" & Chr(64 + NextColumn) & "4:" & Chr(64 + NextColumn) & OutputLastRow & ")*1000"
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for multiplying the row's values:

```
outputSheet.Cells(4,1).Activate 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend

While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 
    -1).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```